# How do I make a class instance accessible in different views for a particular session in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, python-2.6

I am writing a web application in Flask to connect to a virtual machine and run some shell commands remotely. The flow for the system is as follows:

Get VM details, Username and Pswd -> Establish a SSH connection -> Run predefined commands in a specific order with a few user inputs.

For this purpose I have created a class that establishes a SSH connection and has functions to run the commands.

In the Flask view function, a **new instance of this class is created whenever the user logs in**. This serves as an authentication scheme for the application and **this instance needs to be accessible to other views in order to run commands for the logged-in user.** Also, this needs to be session dependent i.e. a new instance of the class needs to be created for another independent request.

The problem is **how to make the class instance variable accessible to other views**. If I make this variable global then it is uniquely set for the whole application and is independent of sessions and requests.

I don't want to store anything in database (user information etc.) as everything is done on the fly.

Below is a snippet of the view.py file:

**ssh_conn is the variable that needs to be accessible to other views. This instance is used in other views like createview to list views for the logged in user.**

I appreciate all the help that I can get and if there are alternative ways to achieve the purpose please do mention them also.

```
from flask import *
from app import app
from form import *
from ssh_connection import ssh


ssh_conn = None;


#
# index page
#
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form=LoginForm()
    ssh_conn = ssh()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if validate_login(request.form['vm_name'], request.form['username'], request.form['password']):
            return redirect('/flow/createview/')

    flash('All fields are mandatory')

    return render_template("login.html", form=form);



@app.route("/flow/createview/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def createview():

    form = createViewForm()
    global ssh_conn;

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #TODO: add create view code


    views = ssh_conn.listviews();

    return render_template("createview.html", form=form, lsviews = views);



# validates login by creating an SSH connection
def validate_login(server, username, password):

    global ssh_conn;

    ssh_conn.__set__(server, username, password);

    ssh_conn_status = ssh_conn.establish_connection();

    if ssh_conn_status == 'success':
        return True;

    flash(ssh_conn_status);
    return False;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Flask's g variable to store the class, it'll do exactly what you want. We use it to stash the User object after we've authenticated them:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/?highlight=g#flask.g